# Count values per X minutes in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I`m trying to watch values in Prometheus per 1 minute.

For example, If in every 30 seconds I'm increasing a counter by 10, that's how the values will be:

```
#Time    Interval     New Counter Value
1        10           10     
31       10           20
61       10           30
91       10           40
121      10           50
151      10           60
...
```

In that example, I want to see in the graph a straight line on value 20 (because in every 60 seconds, the counter increased by 20).

Is it possible to have it in Prometheus?

Answer (score 2):

`round(increase(**myCounter**[60s]))`

Comment: why is a round required here?